# Geolocalização não funciona Google Chrome

Tags: javascript

Alguém com problema de geolocalização não funciona Google Chrome.

Funciona normalmente nos outros navegadores, no chrome não funciona, acompanhe no link abaixo.

http://wernercoiffeur.net/oferta-2016/

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o log informa:

> [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.
>   (anonymous) @ index.php:80

Ou seja `getCurrentPosition` e `watchPosition` não podem ser usadas se sua página não for em HTTPS, isto provavelmente foi inativado em HTTP para evitar que interceptações no meio do caminho obtenham os dados de localização do usuário.

Mais detalhes em: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

### Soluções alternativas

No entanto se deseja pegar a latitude e longitude atual (**não tem** precisão garantida) pode usar algo como desta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39666509/1518921), em JavaScript ficaria algo como:

```
getGEO(function (lat, long) {
    //Aqui você pode setar a latitude e longitude no seu mapa
    console.log(lat, long);
}, function(msg, details) {
    console.log("Erro", msg, details);
});

function getGEO(done, fail){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://ipinfo.io/geo", true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var err;

            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                try {
                    alert(1);
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    var ll = parsed.loc.split(",");
                    done(ll[0], ll[1]);
                } catch (ee) {
                    fail('Parse error', ee);
                }
            } else {
                fail('Request error', xhr.status);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.send(null);
}
```